# How to equalize two .ps files to get same md5 hash

Tags: hash, md5, postscript

I have to somehow equalize two pretty similar files to get the same md5 hashes. I take my inspiration from this work, 
https://natmchugh.blogspot.co.at/2015/05/how-to-make-two-binaries-with-same-md5.html?m=1

But I have to work on Postscript files. My files looks like this:

[image: files]

In which block I have to add some data to get the same files, and get the same hashes.

Comment: School assignment. Have to prepare two files with the same hash to show MD5 collision

Comment: Tough school! well the article links to a tool. You would need to use a tool, it's non-trivial to do yourself

Comment: So it's doesn't work like that, I just have to add for example a comment in specific block of file to have same weight and length?

Comment: If the PostScript program (which looks suspiciously like it was created from a PDF file) is expected to work afterwards, then you will need to add comments (because these won't affect the operation of the program) and you will need to add them in a location which does not affect the functioning of the program, which is harder. Your best bet is to add them to line which are already comments. You haven't supplied a complete example, but I would suggest you look for DSC comments, which are of the form %%Comment: (eg %%Page: 1) and add the comments after that line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
1.It was created in photoshop.
2. Files have same weight but: FIle 1: 47.267 Byte (53 KB auf dem Volume) File 2: 47.267 Byte (49 KB auf dem Volume)
3. I've added commens in the header, but hashes are another. 
4. MD5 (evil_1609910.ps) = e1635f5003b12942dcb9fa4cb0551b6a
MD5 (good_1609910.ps) = 3d10609d366af0edbff8c3998f0b58b3
5. Link to commens, are they in correct place? 
http://i68.tinypic.com/2qa91zk.png

Comment: You can generate postscript QR codes easily here: https://the-burtons.xyz/barcode-generator/ Works a lot better compared to the binary stuff when you are using if else for hash collisions

Answer (score 4):

Two researchers, Magnus Daum and Stefan Lucks, demonstrated a pair of PostScript files with the same MD5 hash but different contents back in 2005. See [*Attacking Hash Functions by Poisoned Messages, "The Story of Alice and her Boss"*](http://web.archive.org/web/20071226014140/http://www.cits.rub.de/MD5Collisions/).

Their pair of PostScript language files are hand-crafted, and have the following form:

```
%!PS-Adobe-1.0
%%BoundingBox: 0 0 612 792                   
(ËB¶jﬁM‡’â_¯Âú¡ß/ ∑ó
F~™¿T>±˚Em3¸S‡[Ô†É£xRÌZ3Œ6ô
únEZRÑyÎ/ΩïıWÂv:Ïø™Ÿ µsY»2Ù},π£v‘6 ˝Ô;É°Ú}Î 6SÜÿk»ÙîÙNa|ÑÄ`œoîµê)(ËB¶jﬁM‡’â_¯Âú¡ß/ ∑ó
F~™¿T>±˚Em3¸S‡[Ô†É£xRÌZ3Œ6ô
únEZRÑyÎ/ΩïıWÂv:Ïø™Ÿ µsY»2Ù},π£v‘6 ˝Ô;É°Ú}Î 6SÜÿk»ÙîÙNa|ÑÄ`œoîµê)eq{
    % Code to print innocent document
}{
    % Code to print evil document
}ifelse
showpage
```

Note that the code has two strings, delimited by parentheses `()`, and tests them for equality. If they are the same, the file prints the innocent document. Otherwise, it prints the evil document.

The PostScript language document which prints the evil document has a slightly different octet sequence in the first string:

```
(ËB¶jﬁM‡’â_¯Âú¡ß/ ∑
F~™¿T>±˚Em3¸S‡[Ô†É#yRÌZ3Œ6ô
únE⁄RÑyÎ/ΩïıWÂv:Ïø™Ÿ µsYH2Ù},π£v‘6 ˝Ô;É°Ú}Î 6SÜXk»ÙîÙNa|ÑÄ`œÔîµê)
```

Both files have the same MD5 digest, `a25f7f0b29ee0b3968c860738533a4b9`.

Since your files include binary data and all manner of other content, the structure they used won't work well for you.   Instead, you can try inserting a string like this in the early part of your file. Put it after the Document Structuring Conventions (lines beginning with `%`) at the start of the file.

```
(0123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789) pop
```

Then use a hash-collision finding tool to identify which octets within the body of that string you need to replace, with which other octets, in order to make one of your PostScript language files match the md5 hash of the other.

Which tool will find hash collisions is not a PostScript-specific question, so is out of the scope of this answer.